# Remove Scroll bar from Iframe tag

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll

I want to use an iframe on a website and use this code:

```
<iframe src="https://dispatchcenter.com/widgets/tall/" width="100%" height="auto" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

But the scrolling bar still shows. If I made anything wrong?
Can anyone help me to remove the scroll bar?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the ability of the user to scroll on that iframe altogether? Also what do you want the height of the iframe to actually be?

Answer (score 0):

First give class to i frame and try this in css,

For Chrome, Safari and Opera:

```
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

For IE and Edge:

```
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

For Firefox:

```
.example {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work in Chrome for the iFrame https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hrsutz7p/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot.

Tested in Chrome and FX.

Chrome hides the body one, but not the iFrame one

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

iframe {
  height: 2000px;
}

.hidescrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}

.hidescrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* Safari, Chrome Edge */
}
```

```html
<body class="hidescrollbar"><!-- does not help in firefox in the fiddle -->
  <iframe class="hidescrollbar" src="javascript:'<body class=hidescrollbar><div style=height:2500px>Hello</div></body>'"></iframe>
</body>
```

If the page is from the same server or a server with CORS enabled, use a div instead and insert using AJAX or via the server